# Firebase saving data

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I'm new to creating databases,
so I have some inputs the user need to fill. To book a time, to like the hairdresser or something. So I get an error when I press book. I don't really understand why the error is happening? So if you could explain why it's happening.

---

Error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
>       at book (app.js:23)
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:22)

Error on line in js file

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

---

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.8/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="p5/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="p5/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type='text' id='inputName' placeholder='full name' style='width:124px;' required>
  <input type='text' id='inputTelefon' placeholder='Telefon number' required>
  <br><br>
  <input type='datetime-local' id='inputDate'>
  <br><br>
  <textarea id='inputMessage' cols='41' rows='10' placeholder='message here...'></textarea>
  <br><br>
  <input onclick="book()" type='button' id='bookBtn' value='Book' style='float:left;font-size:22px;'>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var inputName = document.getElementById('inputName');
var inputTelefon = document.getElementById('inputTelefon');
var inputDatoOgTid = document.getElementById('inputDate');
var inputBesked = document.getElementById('inputMessage');
var bookBtn = document.getElementById('bookBtn');
var database;

function setup() { 
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAJIAVkPZb6AzuezA0POkGdbkX2HDVnGPs",
    authDomain: "okay-5d12f.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://okay-5d12f.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "okay-5d12f",
    storageBucket: "okay-5d12f.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "731997792130"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  database = firebase.database();
}

function book() {
  var data = {
    name: inputName.value(),
    telefon: inputTelefon.value(),
    dateAndTime: inputDatoOgTid.value(),
    message: inputBesked.value()
  }
  console.log(data);
  var ref = database.ref('bookings');
  ref.push(data);
}
```

Comment: should it be inputName.value?

Comment: @arjayosma no, it will just make other bug.

Comment: Did you put this javascript onLoad() Maybe the DOM is not loaded when you called getElementById?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i fixed the bug. I change the var data = {} and made a new book function. 
(The HTML is the same)

---

JavaScript:

```
var inputName; //= document.getElementById('inputName');
var inputTelefon; //= document.getElementById('inputTelefon');
var inputDatoOgTid; //= document.getElementById('inputDate');
var inputBesked; //= document.getElementById('inputMessage');
var database;

function setup() { 
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAJIAVkPZb6AzuezA0POkGdbkX2HDVnGPs",
    authDomain: "okay-5d12f.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://okay-5d12f.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "okay-5d12f",
    storageBucket: "okay-5d12f.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "731997792130"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

function book() {
  var inputName = document.getElementById('inputName').value;
  var inputTelefon = document.getElementById('inputTelefon').value;
  var inputDatoOgTid = document.getElementById('inputDate').value;
  var inputBesked = document.getElementById('inputMessage').value;

  var data = {
    name: inputName,
    telefon: inputTelefon,
    dateAndTime: inputDatoOgTid,
    message: inputBesked 
  }
  database = firebase.database();
  var ref = database.ref('bookings');
  ref.push(data);
  console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to put your javascript code within:

```
window.onload = function() {
  //Your code here
};
```

Since the javascript that you wrote might have fired before the DOM is loaded, and so it will not find the element that you've tried to get.

Comment: Noo. don't think I need that. And I fixed the bug.

Comment: @Tester I tried your suggestion but it is not working in my case also.